# Limit of $\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n}{n^n}$ as $n$ go into infinity

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+(n-1)^n}{n^n}$$

I have found that  the sequence is increasing as $n$ increases. I guess that the answer should be $\frac{1}{1-e}$.

Comment: I doubt the answer is a negative number.